# What's the name of the book with a lizard that has a pet fly?

Tags: story-identification

What's the name of the book that has something that looks like a lizard with a pet fly and he steals a flower and talks to the moon?

Comment: This is very terse. Was this a fantasy novel? Was it a kids novel? Why did he steal a flower? How did he talk to the moon? Did the moon answer back?